# Error in uploading Video to Youtube in Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, gdata

I am trying to upload a video to Youtube using GData and I have been quite successful in doing so.

**PROBLEM**

I have run into a problem in passing different category names, some of which work and some of which do not.

For example, when I pass the video category "Comedy" the video will upload.

But, if I pass any other category, like "Entertainment", then I receive a **400** error.

I haven't any clue why this happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can see the category dropbox in your youtube profile where you can select deferent category like Comedy ,education,Entertainment,gaming,Music ,sport

**Note: you have give same category name which are displayed in category dropbox in your youtube profile**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Give correct category that Youtube Accepts

Comment: i am giving correct category name if u want know which ones than i can tell u.

Answer (score 0):

you can just check the category name from you tube site  where we upload the videos.